# Mac software that automatically switches between applications every several seconds or so?

Tags: macos

I need a Mac software that automatically switches between applications every 10 seconds or so. I need it for a trade show I am participating at.

In the past I've used AutoTab, but it is only for Windows.

Any idea if a similar software exists for Mac?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an AppleScript using the AppleScript Editor in `/Applications/Utilites`. The syntax is quite easy to follow, and I'd base it on something like this:

```
repeat
  tell application "Safari" to activate
  delay 10
  tell application "Finder" to activate
  delay 10
end repeat
```

This will repeatedly have Safari and Finder get focus while waiting 10s in between. Having 10 seconds as an delay should give you enough time to re-open the editor and click on "stop". Another option would be to use `repeat while` instead and to create a stop criterium, like `if exists "/path/to/makeitstop" as POSIX file` which would make it stop after a file makeitstop is created.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I am not a programmer and I can't do that. Doesn't such an application already exist?

Comment: Well, it really is as easy as I described it: you open the Editor app, enter the text posted above and click run. Click stop to stop it. That's it. Try it. It's not complicated at all ;-)